# rearrange an array into a nested array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a table in sql of doctor names and their clients
Each doctor has multiple clients
And one client can visit multiple do doctors
array and a simple table

```
[
{doctor="illies",client=4},
{doctor="illies",client=7},
{doctor="illies",client=1},
{doctor="houari",client=5},
{doctor="abdou",client=1},
{doctor="illies",client=2},
{doctor="abdou",client=1},
]
```

These data are already ordered So the task is To teach client know it's place in the queue
For example
The client with ID 1 Is in the third place in the doctor "illies"
And he's in the first place in the doctor "abdou"
I don't know if I explain it to you well A friend of mine suggest me to
Rearrange the array to a nested array like this (well this array is not totally correct but i has the idea)

```
[doctor="abdou" => clients=[cleint1="1",client2="2" ], doctor="illies"=>clients=[...] ]
```

now i just need an idea that could help me with my projet , all this work it to display the queue of the client (the position of the client in the doctor's queue), and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that each row in the input array can be presented as a class like this:

```java
class DocClient {
    private String doctor;
    private int client;

    public String getDoctor() { return this.doctor; }
    public int getClient() { return this.client; }
}
```

Then array or list of `<DocClient>` needs to be converted not into the "nested array" but into the map where `doctor` is used as a key, and the value is list of `client`s: `Map<String, Integer> docClients`.

This map can be conveniently built using Java Stream API using collectors `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collector.mapping`:

```
List<DocClient> list = Arrays.asList(
    new DocClient("illies", 4), new DocClient("illies", 4), new DocClient("illies", 1),
    new DocClient("houari", 5), new DocClient("abdou", 1), new DocClient("illies", 2),
    new DocClient("abdou", 2)
);

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            DocClient::getDoctor, // use doctor as key via reference to getter 
            Collectors.mapping(
                DocClient::getClient, // use `client` field
                Collectors.toList()   // convert to list
            ) // List<Integer> is value in map entry
        ));
// print the map
// map.forEach((doc, clients) -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", doc. clients));
```